# Make color escape codes work in cgdb

Tags: colors, gdb, cgdb

I have the following function residing in `~/.gdbinit`:

```
define foo
    echo \033[34m
    echo testing...\n
    echo \033[0m
end
```

When running `foo` in `gdb` it prints `testing...` in blue, however, when running it in `cgdb`  the result is:

```
[34mtesting...
[0m
```

How can I enable color escape codes in `cgdb`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the gdb "window" in cgdb is not a full-fledged terminal... it can handle basic text I/O but it will not render any terminal escape sequences such as colors, cursor movement, etc.